# Getting Apache/PHPUnit to run on Windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, phpunit

I am trying to get PHP Unit to run on my Windows. Here is what I have tried to get it to work:

- Installed PHPUnit - but it said I had the wrong version of PHP on.
- I uninstalled WAMP, because that was where PHPUnit was looking for PHP.
- I tried to find the `httd` conf file, but couldn't find it so I ended up installing Apache in my root directory. But I don't think that made any difference, because I could still boot my local host even when Apache was not in my root directory.
- I installed PHP 7 in my root directory
- To run my localhost server I now have to right `.\php` instead of just php.

So I am not quite sure where to go now. My computer now says that PHP is not a recognized as an internal or external command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the PHP directory to you path environment variable. [How to do it depends on your Windows version.](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

After adjusting the environment variable you have to reopen the command window for the changes to take effect.